# Neo4jPHP - Working with many entities in a result set

Tags: php, neo4j, neo4jphp

I am returning several entities in a Cypher query where a few are singular and a few others could have many. For example, if I were to `RETURN name, dob, address`, `name` would return one object, `dob` would return one object, and `addresses` could return several objects.

How do I loop through the result set getting the right data and collecting it in to an array that makes sense? For example:

```
$array = array(
    name = 'name',
    dob = 'd/o/b',
    addresses = array(
        array(
           'myData'
        ),
        array(
           'myData'
        )
    )
)
```

So far when I `foreach($result as $row)` row contains duplicates for `name` and `dob` for each different `address`.

This is my Cypher query:

```
MATCH  (creator:CreatingUser)-[:creator]-(event:Event), (occurrence:EventSpaceTimeOccurrence)-[:occurrence]-(event)
WHERE  creator.id = '1234'
RETURN event, creator, occurrence
```

Comment: What does your full Cypher query look like?

Comment: `MATCH (creator:CreatingUser)-[:creator]-(event:Event), (occurrence:EventSpaceTimeOccurrence)-[:occurrence]-(event)
WHERE creator.id = '1234'
RETURN event, creator, occurrence`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `distinct` keyword:

```
MATCH  (creator:CreatingUser)-[:creator]-(event:Event), (occurrence:EventSpaceTimeOccurrence)-[:occurrence]-(event)
WHERE  creator.id = '1234'
RETURN DISTINCT event, creator, occurrence
```